# Changing the title of the header

Tags: node.js, sapui5

I use the SAPUI5 Framework.
Within a page there are two possibilities for action, to make a new patient and to edit a patient. The new and edit, control/view pages are compiled into one, one control and one view for both new and edit.

Since they both are within one-page control/view, whenever I try to make a new patient or to edit a patient I get the same title for both of these Options.

My approach.

1. Get the URL of the page -> New or Edit. -> Split till I get, if it's new or edit.
2. If its new, change the title to New if edit that the title to Edit.

```
var completurl = window.location.href;
var split = completurl.split("/");
if(split[7] == 'new'){
   this.byId("semantic:DetailPageID").setTitle("New");
}  
else {
  this.byId("semantic:DetailPageID").setTitle("Edit");
}
```

Expected: To change the title of the header.
Actuality: Doesn't do shit

Answer (score 2):

First you need the different buttons in your main.view.xml.

main.view.xml:

```
<Button press="onPressNew" text="New"/>
<Button press="onPressEdit" text="Edit"/>
```

Now you could use a local model for saving the action

editNew.controller.js:

```
onPressEdit: function () {
    this.myLocalModel.setProperty("/Action", "Edit");
    //Navigate to editNew.view.xml
},
onPressNew: function () {
    this.myLocalModel.setProperty("/Action", "New");
    //Navigate to editNew.view.xml
}
```

In your editNew.view.xml, you could use [expression binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0)

editNew.view.xml:

```
<Page id="pageEditNew" title="{= ${localModel>/Action} === 'Edit' ? ${i18n>title_edit} : ${i18n>title_new}}">
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i need a bit of unpacking. onPressEdit - > should it be the id of the edit button?. this.myLocalModel.setProperty will just change the title of the header? but doing it in controller will it change it for the view.xml <Page> ? if in title i use ${localModel/Action} === 'Edit' should it be EditId or on what is based 'Edit' ?

Comment: do you have multiple Edit buttons?
If property "Action" is changed in controller the title in view will be changed immediately.

Comment: No, there is only one Edit and New. but the onPressNew what is the later part 'New' based on? its name/id?

Comment: In your pageEditNew view is an press event on the "new" and "edit" button. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The buttons aren't in editNew view rather in your e.g. main view

Comment: Correct buttons edit/new are in patientcontroller, by clicking which you come to a edit/new page with the same controller and view page